# Phonegap & Titanium performance and stability differences in Form elements

Tags: cordova, titanium, cross-platform

We need a mobile application which will not have any device management related functionalities. The application will only have forms.

What I want to know, it is always said that titanium's perfomance and stability is better than phonegap because it creates native codes. Will there be a significant difference in performance or stability if I only have forms in my application (no location, no contact list control etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course there will be a difference of perfomance . (native code vs rendering html5/css)

however ,if you have a form with 3textfield & the submit button. there won't be a any difference (0.20 sec ? O.o xD ) .

contrario if you have a form with 30 question who have each 4 radioButton or more. You will  feal it.

by experiment , You will really feel the difference if you developpe an apply which containt more than 1 window or if you need to manipulate things like camera/contact-list /etc... .